# Visual Studio C++ Extensibility Template Project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, project-template

I am able to generate C# template projects using the File--> New-->Visual C#-->Extensibility-->C# Project Template option in Visual Studio 2012.

But I need to do the same for a C++ dll project.  How can I do it for C++?? I dont see any option for generating this in Visual Studio.

Comment: Why do you want to do an extensibility project using C++?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have 2012 on my machine to verify but this is how Microsoft says to create project templates.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes this is the manual way of doing it, but if you download the Visual Studio SDK (From here for 2012 http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30668) Then there is a menu option of generating C# project templates.  I was wondering if there is a way of doing the same for C++ projects.

Comment: ah, OK.  Well I don't know that, but I would hazard a guess, no.  Hopefully someone get give you a better answer.